# How to take Native iOS Screenshots using Appium (preferably python) and see them in device/simulator Photo album automatically?

Tags: python, ios, path, appium, screenshot

I am trying to automate taking screenshot and uploading via photo album in iOS Simulator. If we use Appium save_screenshot(output), we don't know the photo album path or don't have permissions to write explicitly in to the Photo Album. Instead we are forced to save the screen shot to a path in our computer/project.

I have tried these two:

1. screenshotBase64 = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
2. file  = ((TakesScreenshot)self.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

.

```
screenshotBase64 = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()

file  = ((TakesScreenshot)self.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Expected: Screenshot taken and saved into the photo Album
Actual: Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

There is no single command for this, you will have to go for the following combination:

1. [Screenshot](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/screenshot/) - take a screenshot as Base64 string
2. [Push File](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file/) - save the screenshot on the iOS device

Like:

```
screenshotBase64 = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
driver.push_file('/path/to/device/foo.bar', screenshotBase64)
```

You might also be interested in [SeeTest - Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension) commands which fill Appium's gaps

Comment: Seeing the below Exception when I try 1.Screenshot 2.Push File
 WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: simctl error running 'addmedia': Failed to import '/var/folders/vq/vztd6tv95ml3dbt2sk2x6_xc0000gn/T/2019631-3218-5911mr.dwtj9/device', error [NSPOSIXErrorDomain] 22: The operation couldn’t be completed. File type unsupported.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked when I added the extension as .png after the device/image_name.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use the driver to save the screenshot as a file:

```
self.wd = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:{0}/wd/hub'.format(self.port), self.desired_caps)
self.wd.get_screenshot_as_file('{0}.jpg'.format(self.desired_caps['deviceName']))
```